# How to use bootstrap confirmation modal to delete the selected checkbox rows? SQL & MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a delete button which when clicked opens up a confirmation message. After the confirmation message is clicked to continue the delete process. It send the information to the controller to see which checkbox(s) were selected and delete the specific rows. My problem is when the confirmation button is clicked the page redirects but the row has not been deleted.

I have tried using html begin form and wrapping it around the button to confirm in order to send the information to the controller, but failed.

```cs
public ActionResult DelSelfSupp(string [] suppids)
        {
            int[] getid = null;
            if(suppids != null)
            {
                getid = new int[suppids.Length];
                int j = 0;
                foreach(string i in suppids)
                {
                    int.TryParse(i, out getid[j++]);
                }

                List<Supplier> getsuppids = new List<Supplier>();
                GumtionDBEntities db = new GumtionDBEntities();
                getsuppids = db.Suppliers.Where(x => getid.Contains(x.SupplierID)).ToList();
                foreach(var s in getsuppids)
                {
                    db.Suppliers.Remove(s);
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Home");
        }
```

```html
 <div id="deleteEmployeeModalTop" class="modal fade">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <form>
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Supplier?</h4>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <p>Are you sure you want to delete these the Supplier?</p>
                                    <p class="text-warning">
                                        <small>This action cannot be undone.</small>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">

                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel">


                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete Selected Supplier(s)" data-target="#confirmDoubleModalTop" data-toggle="modal">Delete Selected Supplier(s) </button>


                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

```html
 <div class="table-wrapper">
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="background:white; position: sticky; top: 0;">
                                <span class="custom-checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll">
                                    <label for="selectAll"></label>
                                </span>
                            </th>
                            <th style="background:white; position: sticky; top: 0;">Company Name</th>
                            <th style="background:white; position: sticky; top: 0;">Contact No.</th>
                            <th style="background:white; position: sticky; top: 0;">Contact Name</th>
                            <th style="background:white; position: sticky; top: 0;">Address</th>
                            <th style="background:white; position: sticky; top: 0;">Email</th>
                            <th style="background:white; position: sticky; top: 0;">Banking Details</th>
                            <th style="width:10%;  background:white; position: sticky; top: 0;">Edit</th>
                            <th style="width:10%;z-index:1; background:white; position: sticky; top: 0;">Delete</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="custom-checkbox">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="suppids" value="@item.SupplierID">
                                        <label for="checkbox1">@item.SupplierID</label>
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                                <td>@item.SupplierCompanyName</td>
                                <td>@item.SupplierContactNo</td>
                                <td>@item.SupplierContactName</td>
                                <td>@item.SupplierAddress</td>
                                <td>@item.SupplierContactEmail</td>
                                <td>@item.SupplierBankDetails</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="#editEmployeeModal" class="edit" data-toggle="modal">
                                        <i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">&#xE254;</i>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td>

                                    @item.SupplierID
                                    <input type="submit" class="material-icons" data-toggle="modal" title="Delete" value="&#xE872;" data-target="#deleteEmployeeModal" />

                                    @using (Html.BeginForm("SingleDel", "Supplier", new { suppID = item.SupplierID }))
                                    {
                                        <div id="deleteEmployeeModal" class="modal fade">
                                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                                <div class="modal-content">
                                                    <form>
                                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                                            <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Order</h4>
                                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                                            <p>Are you sure you want to delete these Records?</p>
                                                            <p class="text-warning">
                                                                <small>This action cannot be undone.</small>
                                                            </p>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="modal-footer">

                                                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel">
                                                            @*<a href="#DoubleconfirmModalDeleteBottom" class="delete" data-toggle="modal">*@

                                                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete" data-target="#confirmDoubleModalTop" data-toggle="modal">

                                                            @*</a>*@
                                                        </div>
                                                    </form>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    }
                                </td>


                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

I expect the result to be after confirmation button is selected the selected checkbox(s) are deleted

Comment: You need to provide HTML markup for checkboxes list too. :)

Comment: @mwilczynski Added it